# Unable to delete Apache Atlas Classification

Tags: apache-atlas

I have a list of Classifications &  Sub-classifications in Apache Atlas. Want to delete them & create a new list.
All the other classifications are getting deleted but one of them with name "PII" giving following error when we select Delete Classification.

[image]

Error: **Given type PII has references**

When we do a search via Rest API using below URL:
http://ip.of.atlas:21000/api/atlas/v2/search/basic?classification=PII

Following Result comes:

```
{
    "queryType": "BASIC",
    "searchParameters": {
        "classification": "PII",
        "excludeDeletedEntities": false,
        "includeClassificationAttributes": false,
        "includeSubTypes": true,
        "includeSubClassifications": true,
        "limit": 100,
        "offset": 0
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "typeName": "hive_table",
            "attributes": {
                "owner": "nifi",
                "createTime": 1557832055000,
                "qualifiedName": "demo.test_table@demopilot",
                "name": "test_table"
            },
            "guid": "ecb7bb24-bdde-448c-b718-07273e5ce572",
            "status": "DELETED",
            "displayText": "test_table",
            "classificationNames": [
                "PII"
            ],
            "meaningNames": [],
            "meanings": []
        },
        {
            "typeName": "hive_table",
            "attributes": {
                "owner": "nifi",
                "createTime": 1557832055000,
                "qualifiedName": "demo.test_table@demopilot",
                "name": "test_table"
            },
            "guid": "ed5a9284-c290-4431-ab76-27b820478e29",
            "status": "DELETED",
            "displayText": "test_table",
            "classificationNames": [
                "PII"
            ],
            "meaningNames": [],
            "meanings": []
        },
        {
            "typeName": "hive_column",
            "attributes": {
                "owner": "nifi",
                "qualifiedName": "demo.test_table.traffic_case@demopilot",
                "name": "traffic_case"
            },
            "guid": "73f75a6c-9f4e-41f0-b0ef-6c05ca132639",
            "status": "DELETED",
            "displayText": "traffic_case",
            "classificationNames": [
                "PII"
            ],
            "meaningNames": [],
            "meanings": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Questions:
1. Is there a API which help to delete all Classifications irrespective of whether they are attached to Entity or not?
2. Delete Single Classification forcefully with Classification Name or GUID?

Answer (score 0):

Running below GET request:
http://ip.of.atlas:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs

& then Delete the guid attached to the typedefs

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out and you could use below API to delete a tag:

```
curl -k -X DELETE --insecure --negotiate -u :  --header \
''{"classificationDefs":[{"name":"PII","superTypes":[],"attributeDefs":[]}]}' \
'https://atlas-host:21443/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs?type=classification'
```